# High capacity buffer fifo or use of a file as buffer for a fifo

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, fifo

In a bash script i pipe the output of a command into the input of another using:

```
$ output_com | input_com
```

`output_com` is slower than `input_com`. In my script, before `input_com` is ready to operate, some other commands needs to be executed.

In order to speed up things, i would like to start `output_com` at the beginning of the script, outputing into some kind of high capacity fifo, do others commands thats needs to be done then execute `input_com` with the fifo in input. Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
mkfifo /tmp/fifo
output_com > /tmp/fifo &

somecommand1
somecommand2
input_com < /tmp/fifo
```

Unfortunatelly the buffer size of fifos is too small for my use case so `output_com` is quickly blocked before `input_com` starts to read. 
The volume of data shared between theses to commands can vary from 500MB to 1GB approx.

Is there some mechanism, tool or concept i'm not aware of that could allow `output_com` to start to buffer many MBs on the fifo before `input_com` starts to read ?

For example, it would be great if the fifo buffer could be baked by a tmp file (hdd used as buffer) but i have not found how to do that. Using a simple file is non blocking and makes `input_com` to terminate before `output_com` finishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tool called [buffer](https://linux.die.net/man/1/buffer) that works like a bigger pipe. It isn't installed by default in most distros, but it can be installed from the package manager.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
mkfifo /tmp/fifo
output_com | buffer -m 1024m -s 512k > /tmp/fifo &

somecommand1
somecommand2
input_com < /tmp/fifo
wait
```

Sadly the manual does nos specify the maximum number of blocks that `buffer` can work with, nor the maximum size of the buffers, but that should give you a 1GiB buffer.

Comment: Thank you that's what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating the fifo file in RAM? The buffer size should be less of an issue.

/dev/shm is a special folder where everything you write to it gets stored in memory rather than the harddisk. Try and see if this speeds things up:

```
#!/bin/bash

ramdisk=/dev/shm
fifo=$ramdisk/fifo
mkfifo $fifo
output_com > $fifo &

somecommand1
somecommand2
wait
input_com < $fifo
```

Comment: Hi, i don't think the buffer size of a FIFO depends on the file system type the FIFO is created but has a fixed size (set on kernel?). On `pipe(7)` it is written "Since Linux 2.6.11, The capacity of a pipe is 65536 bytes" (translated from french man page).